# start timer on mouse out interrupt timer on mouseover javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, timer, volume

im trying to make a volume bar for a video. 
the concept is that when you click the volume button, a div appears, and you can control the volume level with it. when you hover out from the div a counter starts counting down from 7 and makes the div disappear.
however, if the counter started and you hover back on the volume controler, the counter is stopped.
I dont know how to interrupt the timer from counting down. any input?

this is what i got so far.

```
  //event for volume bar
  volumeC.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    volumeC.style.display = 'inline-block';
  });

  volumeC.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
     timer = setTimeout(function () {
        volumeC.style.display = 'none';
      }, 7000);
  });
```

Comment: How does your question title relate to your question in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear timeout with `clearTimeout` put in `mouseover` handler:

```
var timer;

volumeC.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    volumeC.style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```